# Appengine Full Text Search - Precision of numeric fields in the Search API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-search

While testing the search api locally (Java SDK - 1.9.6) i'm getting unexpected results doing equality and range checks against numbers which are small.

For example, if i index three documents with the following fields:

```
numeric: 0.0011
numeric: 0.0022
numeric: 0.0033
```

I get the following results for the following queries:

```
numeric: 0.0033 -> []
numeric= 0.0033 -> []
numeric>= 0.0033 -> []
numeric < 0.0033 -> [document1, document2, document3]
numeric < 0.0022 -> [document1, document2]
numeric < 0.0021 -> [document1, document2]
numeric < 0.002 -> [document1]
```

I assume there is something in the implementation which indexes or runs queries against numbers at a granularity other than exact? Should I expect these
results to be reflected in the real appengine environments? What precision can I rely on?

The main challenge i am trying to solve is the ability to store numbers which fall outside of the SearchApiLimits.MINIMUM_NUMBER_VALUE and SearchApiLimits.MAXIMUM_NUMBER_VALUE and still operate on them. At the moment, shifting them by moving the decimal place is the only option I have been able to come up. Are there any alternatives that allow good control over how much precision is lost in the translation first to a double (the type in the java api), and then whatever is happening under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question,

I have not been able to reproduce your results with the newest version of the API. If you can reproduce your results in version 1.9.7 then post some code and I'll take a look at it again. The dev server and the production server should behave the same, and if not, then it is a bug.

One alternative to get around the limits is by not storing them as numbers but as atoms. But then you won't be able to apply the <,>,<=,..., operators only equality.

Comment: Here is a Gist which shows the failures i'm seeing. https://gist.github.com/atomicleopard/979f9ac01c45d1fafc43

Comment: I have filed a bug against it. That should at least result in better documentation. As of now, it seems that the granularity is 2.

Comment: Could you expand on what the implication of a granularity of 2 means? As in 0.0002, or numeric results are grouped together in groups of two? And if you are in a position to, whether or not this is true of both the dev server and the appengine environment itself, or just the dev server?

Comment: The dev server and the production environment does not share the same implementation. However, if they don't behave alike it is considered a bug and can be filed here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/. I still can't replicate 'numeric = 0.0033' but I do see some of your results for '<', etc. Basically, the granularity means that numbers are grouped into [0,2[, [2,4[, etc. and therefore you will see false positives. In some cases, however, it's possible to filter the output. I don't have the exact information on this topic so you have to wait for updated documentation.

Comment: I've filed an issue, but based on previous experience, it would probably be quicker to just send it straight to /dev/null. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that the local FTS is not the same code as the App Engine server.  I think it's lucene or something.